# UITableView stopped loading data in IOS7 and Xcode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I have a simple view which has been successfully loading a table of data from CoreData for the last 18 months. It even works now on devices that have been upgraded to IOS 7. But when I upgraded to Xcode5 and run through the IOS7 3.5inch retina simulator my table is always empty. I have pasted my code below and I can confirm that the fetchRequests are returning the data because I can see this in the NSLog outputs. But why has be table stopped populating the cells?

I feel really stupid because I just cannot figure this one out…

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        NSLog(@"listData count in numberOFRowsInSection is: %i", listData.count);
        return [self.listData count];
    }

    - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        Sessions *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"info content is: %@", info.sport);
        //Format cell data ready to be displayed
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, dd LLL yyyy"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:info.date];

        NSNumber *dist1Nbr = info.dist1;
        int dist1Int = [dist1Nbr integerValue];
        float distIntKorM = ([dist1Nbr integerValue])/1000;
        NSString *dist1StrMeters = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", dist1Int];
        NSString *dist1StrKorM = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.01f", distIntKorM];


        //Select image to display
        if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Run"]) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trainers-15x10.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@", info.sessiontype, dist1StrKorM];
            NSLog(@"Cell text for Runs shoudl be: %@", cell.textLabel.text);
        } else if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Other"]) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"weights-15x10.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@", info.sessiontype, dist1StrKorM];
        } else if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Swim"]) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goggles-15x10.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@m", info.sessiontype, dist1StrMeters];
            NSLog(@"Cell text for Swims shoudl be: %@", cell.textLabel.text);
        } else if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Cycle"]) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bike-15x10.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@", info.sessiontype, dist1StrKorM];
        } else if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Brick"]) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brick-15x10.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@", info.sessiontype, dist1StrKorM];
        }

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"editSession";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            }
            // this cell backgrond colour alternating works!
            UIView *bgColor = [cell viewWithTag:100];
            if (!bgColor) {
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
                bgColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                bgColor.tag = 100;
                [cell addSubview:bgColor];
                [cell sendSubviewToBack:bgColor];
            }

            if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
                bgColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0 green:233.0/255.0 blue:233.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                    } else {
                        bgColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];                                }

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
        if (_context == nil) 
        { 
            _context = [(SGK_T4T_01AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
            NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  _context);
        }

        NSError *error;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"After fetchedResultsController: %@",  _fetchedResultsController);
            //NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  _fetchedResultsController);
        }
        self.title = @"Sessions";


    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

        [self setListData:nil];
        [self setSelectedSession:nil];
        [self setSessionSport:nil];
        //[self setRecordCount:nil];
        [self setFetchedResultsController:nil];
        [self setContext:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        SGK_T4T_01AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDiscription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sessions" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"refid" ascending:YES];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:entityDiscription];


        NSError *error;
        NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (objects == nil) {

            NSLog(@"The fetch request returned an array == nil");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The fetch request returned an array!!!");
            NSLog(@"objects contents is: %@", objects);
            NSLog(@"objects count = %i", [objects count]);
            listData = objects;
            NSLog(@"listData count = %i", [listData count]);
            //NSUInteger *recordCount = [objects count];
            recordCount = [objects count];
        }

        //reload tableView:dataSource from CoreData when view reappears...
        if (_context == nil)
        {
            _context = [(SGK_T4T_01AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  _context);
        }

        NSError *error1;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error1]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error1, [error1 userInfo]);
            exit(-1);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"viewWillAppear: fetchedResultsController: %@",  _fetchedResultsController);
        }
        //end of reload tableView:dataSource from CoreData when view reappears...

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        //[self setFetchedResultsController:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
        //[self setFetchedResultsController:nil];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }
    */


    // Override to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            [_context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![_context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
                }
            } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
        if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSUInteger index = indexPath.row;
        //NSLog(@" Prep4Seg indexPath.row = %u", index);
        //NSLog(@" Prep4Seg recordCount = %u", recordCount);
        /*
            Subtract the row index from the row count to get the correct position in the Array (because I am sorting on date order so tableCell position 0 is position 2 in the Array (if there are 3 only items in the table and array) so if you don't invert the indexPath you end up passing the last item instead of the first or second last item instead of the second and so on...
         */
        NSUInteger arrayIndex = (recordCount-index-1);
        //NSLog(@" Prep4Seg arrayIndex = %u", arrayIndex);
        selectedSession = [listData objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];
        //NSLog(@"listData = %@", listData);
        //NSLog(@"SelectedSession = %@", selectedSession);

        NSNumber *refId = [selectedSession valueForKey:@"refid"];
        NSString *refIdToSend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", refId];
        NSLog(@"Prep4Seg in tableView: refIdToSend = %@", refIdToSend);

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editSession"]) {
            SGK_T4T_EditSessionDetail *editSessionDetail = segue.destinationViewController;
            editSessionDetail.delegate = (id)self;
            editSessionDetail.returnFromDatePickerView = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"no"];
            editSessionDetail.recedIndex = refIdToSend;
        }
    }

    - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
        // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }


    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

        switch(type) {

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }


    - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
        // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

And my log output is:

```
2013-11-09 16:04:04.034 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] After managedObjectContext: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xb589bc0>
2013-11-09 16:04:04.036 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] After fetchedResultsController: <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xb5e2c40>
2013-11-09 16:04:04.040 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] The fetch request returned an array!!!
2013-11-09 16:04:04.041 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] objects contents is: (
    "<NSManagedObject: 0xb5c8570> (entity: Sessions; id: 0xb5ac970 <x-coredata://B93EE0DE-E6FA-491C-9C8F-23692A36DD0C/Sessions/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0xb5d6320> (entity: Sessions; id: 0xb58a2a0 <x-coredata://B93EE0DE-E6FA-491C-9C8F-23692A36DD0C/Sessions/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0xb5d0370> (entity: Sessions; id: 0xb5dc270 <x-coredata://B93EE0DE-E6FA-491C-9C8F-23692A36DD0C/Sessions/p3> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0xb5e3dd0> (entity: Sessions; id: 0xb5ebcc0 <x-coredata://B93EE0DE-E6FA-491C-9C8F-23692A36DD0C/Sessions/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0xb585e40> (entity: Sessions; id: 0xb5e4e40 <x-coredata://B93EE0DE-E6FA-491C-9C8F-23692A36DD0C/Sessions/p5> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2013-11-09 16:04:04.041 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] objects count = 5
2013-11-09 16:04:04.042 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] listData count = 5
2013-11-09 16:04:04.043 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] viewWillAppear: fetchedResultsController: <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xb5a01e0>
2013-11-09 16:04:04.043 trainForTri copy[6509:a0b] listData count in numberOFRowsInSection is: 5
```

Comment: Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called?  Also, you print `listData.count` and return `[self.listData count]`...are you sure those are the same things?  (property vs. variable?)

Comment: I bet @PhillipMills is right. You have explicitly created a `listData` ivar and didn't `@synthesize listData`, so it's using an implicit `_listData` for the property. This is just one more reason you should **always use `.property` and avoid direct ivars**.

Comment: @PhillipMills and Thank you both for your comments. I do synthesise listData and even if I change it to {return [listData count];} it makes no difference. And I have tested by placing an NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath but I do not get an output - so I guess it's not being called - but why when it always did before Xcode5. Any further ideas because I am stumped!

Comment: Can you post more code, such as a test app replicating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the issue with this. Eventually after almost wanting to throw my Macbook out of the window in frustration with Xcode5 I shut everything down and restarted. when I opened Xcode, built and ran my App it lo longer loaded an empty table - it now produced an error which indicated that there was something wrong with my NSFetchedResultsController. I traced it to an issue with the cache not clearing (or not being mutable) - so I removed the cache name and set it to nil and everything is working again. I am not sure if this is an IOS7/Xcode5 issue but it has not been a problem until this upgrade. For anyone searching for a similar fix here is the offending line of code:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
```

And this is the version that works!

```
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

I hope I'm not the only one ever to struggle with this and therefore just a thickie!